# How to Ignore filters for specific visualization/Lens in a dashboard

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I have multiple Visualization lens on kibana dashboard, I want ignore the global filters for few of the lenses, How can I do that.

I am creating lens under kibana dashboard not in TSVB.

If I apply global filters then it should be not applied on the specific visualization in kibana dashboard.

Comment: maybe you can *disable* that filter temporarily

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to ignore global filters yet in not TSVB visualizations.

There are some open issues about that though:

https://github.com/elastic/kibana/issues/112328

https://github.com/elastic/kibana/issues/143493

Answer (score 0):

This is not officially provided currently (at least Kibana 8.6.2), but I found a workaround.

This workaround is also mentioned in [this topic](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/selective-filter-on-kibana-dashboard/143419) in the Elastic community, but I will explain more detailed steps here.

You can achieve this by doing the following steps, using multiple data views.

1. Create multiple data views for the same index

   - Assume that you have the following data views and index

     - data view1 (based on the indexA)
     - data view2 (based on the indexA)
2. Assuming that you want to filter by fieldA in indexA, add fieldA' [runtime field](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/8.6/runtime.html) whose value is same as fieldA to data view1.

   - The following screenshot is an example settings to add a runtime field.
     [image]
3. Create visualizations, some of them are from data view1 and the others are from data view2.
4. Filter by fieldA' so you can see that only the visualizations from data view1 is filterd.

Note that you should set `courier:ignoreFilterIfFieldNotInIndex` = true before all (see [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/current/advanced-options.html) for more details). You can do this in "Stack Management >
Advanced Settings".

Finally let me show you an example dashboard. The below dashboard is based on the official sample data "Sample web logs". In this dashboard, the left visualization is filtered by URL, but the right one isn't.
[image]

Comment: I have tried this by creating 2 different index patter on single index by adding run time fields with different name. However when I apply filter it gets applied on all charts present in same dashboard.